# CSS Gradient not transitioning from end to end

Tags: html, css

My css gradient animation is working except all parts are changing at the same time not running from end to end like this www.verily.com, here is what I tried,

```
    .animated  {
  -webkit-animation: animated1 20s infinite;
  animation: animated1 20s infinite;
}



@-webkit-keyframes animated1 {
    0%,
    100% {
        background-color: #2878ff
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #ff1643
    }
}

@keyframes animated1 {
    0%,
    100% {
        background-color: #2878ff
    }
    50% {
        background-color: #ff1643
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not a gradient, just background-color , the behavior you notice is normal. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that code, it fade the color nicely as you can see in this fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/y3kavc0w/, so how do you mean it does not work?

Comment: how to animate a linear gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to animate a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #f51313, #fbf708);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  -webkit-animation: anim 10s ease infinite;
  animation: anim 10s ease infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  0%, 100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
}
@keyframes anim {
  0%, 100% {
    background-position: 0% 50%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the way verily achieves their effect is by animating an image.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.verily-hero-image-gradient{
  background-image: url(//verily.com/img/gradient-loop.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  animation: hero-gradient-loop 20s infinite;
  display: block;
  height: 1000%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

@keyframes hero-gradient-loop{
  0%{
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  }
  100%{
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);
    transform:translate3d(0,-50%,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="verily-hero-image-gradient"></div>
```